# spring jpa embeddable class send int instead of Object

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller, embeddable

I have a little problem between my RestController response and my AngularJs Controller.

First, I'm calling my rest webservice with $http :

```
myModule.controller('UserDetailsCtrl',function($http, idUser){

    var self = this;

    $http.post('/get-user-details', idUser).then(
        function(response){        

            self.clients = response.data.usersClients;

            for(client of self.clients){                    
                console.log("pkUsersClients : " + client.pkUsersClients); // console display "[object Object]"
                console.log("client : " + client.pkUsersClients.client); // console display "1" instead of User Object
                console.log("keys : " + Object.keys(client.pkUsersClients)); // console display "keys : user,client"
                console.log("name : " + client.pkUsersClients.client.name); // display "undefined"
            }

        },    function(){
            // error
        }
    );

});
```

Then, I have my spring @RestController :

```
@RestController
public class UserDetailsRest {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private UserDatasDao userDatasDao;

    @Autowired
    private UsersClientsDao usersClientsDao;

    @RequestMapping("get-user-details")
    public UserDetailsDto getUserDetails(@RequestBody Long idUser){

        User user = userDao.findByIdUser(idUser);

        UserDatas userDatas = userDatasDao.findByIdUser(user);

        List<UsersClients> usersClients = usersClientsDao.findByPkUsersClientsUser(user);

        UserDetailsDto userDetailsDto = new UserDetailsDto(userDatas, usersClients);

        return userDetailsDto; 
        // userDetailsDto contains : List<UsersClients> (2 lines). In each line, UsersClients contains : UserClientId pkUsersClients. Which contains : User + Client.
        // But in Angular, User and Client are int and int (the id in fact).

    }

}
```

So, my issue is that :

- my webservice return an object UserDetailsDto which contains:

  private List usersClients;
- each UsersClients in this List contains :

  private List usersClients;

  private UserClientId pkUsersClients
- pkUsersClients is a @Embeddable Object which contains :

  private User user;

  private Client client;
- in angularjs, User and Client are not Object but int.

My classes :

- my DTO which is the response

  ```
  public class UserDetailsDto {

      private List<UsersClients> usersClients;

      public UserDetailsDto(List<UsersClients> _usersClients) {
          super();
          this.usersClients = _usersClients;
      }

      // getters/setters
      // toString override

  }
  ```
- My association table :

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="users_clients")
  @AssociationOverrides(
      {
          @AssociationOverride(
              name="pkUsersClients.user",
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
          ),
          @AssociationOverride(
              name="pkUsersClients.client",
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="id_client")        
          )
      }
  )
  public class UsersClients {

      private UserClientId pkUsersClients = new UserClientId();

      @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
      private Date date_begin;

      @EmbeddedId
      public UserClientId getPkUsersClients() {
          return pkUsersClients;
      }

      public void setPkUsersClients(UserClientId pkUsersClients) {
          this.pkUsersClients = pkUsersClients;
      }

      @Transient
      public User getUser() {
          return getPkUsersClients().getUser();
      }

      public void setUser(User user) {
          getPkUsersClients().setUser(user);
      }

      @Transient
      public Client getIdClient() {
          return getPkUsersClients().getClient();
      }

      public void setIdClient(Client client) {
          getPkUsersClients().setClient(client);
      }

      public Date getDate_begin() {
          return date_begin;
      }

      public void setDate_begin(Date date_begin) {
          this.date_begin = date_begin;
      }

  }
  ```
- to finish, my embeddable class :

  ```
  @Embeddable
  public class UserClientId implements Serializable{

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      private User user;
      private Client client;

      /**
       * @return the user
       */
      @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
      public User getUser() {
          return user;
      }

      /**
       * @param user the user to set
       */
      public void setUser(User user) {
          this.user = user;
      }

      /**
       * @return the client
       */
      @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
      public Client getClient() {
          return client;
      }

      /**
       * @param client the client to set
       */
      public void setClient(Client client) {
          this.client = client;
      }
  }
  ```

EDIT : With chrome developper tools, I can see that client = "1" BUT user is an object. Now, the problem is that my response contains :

```
{
  "avatar": null,
  "identity": "M. edith USER",
  "login": "EditUser",
  "address": "125, rue du test. testLand (testLand)",
  "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
  "idUser": 31,
  "usersClients": [
    {
      "pkUsersClients": {
        "user": {
          "idUser": 31,
          "login": "EditUser",
          "pwd": "$2a$10$7G/GWrd5e3d3SVkZL5.EbOwbXP7NABCVxTPJVRZ0AVJYMtP/bgx.K",
          "locked": "F",
          "avatar": null,
          "usersClients": [
            {
              "pkUsersClients": {
                "user": 31,
                "client": {
                  "idClient": 5,
                  "name": "BBBBBBBB",
                  "description": "TEST",
                  "logo": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAG..."
                }
              },
              "date_begin": 1464818400000,
              "date_end": 1467237600000,
              "enable": false,
              "user": 31,
              "idClient": 5
            },
            {
              "pkUsersClients": {
                "user": 31,
                "client": {
                  "idClient": 1,
                  "name": "AAAAAA",
                  "description": "La société Inside Group...",
                  "logo": "/9j/4QDCRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAHABIBAwABA..."
                }
              },
              "date_begin": null,
              "date_end": null,
              "enable": false,
              "user": 31,
              "idClient": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        "client": 1
      },
      "date_begin": null,
      "date_end": null,
      "enable": false,
      "user": 31,
      "idClient": 1
    },
    {
      "pkUsersClients": {
        "user": 31,
        "client": 1
      },
      "date_begin": null,
      "date_end": null,
      "enable": false,
      "user": 31,
      "idClient": 1
    },
    {
      "pkUsersClients": {
        "user": 31,
        "client": 5
      },
      "date_begin": 1464818400000,
      "date_end": 1467237600000,
      "enable": false,
      "user": 31,
      "idClient": 5
    }
  ]
```

You can see that it is a little disturbing :/

Please, give me some help, I don't understand where I make a mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: as a side note: I'd recommend inspecting the actual response from your REST API via Developer Tools instead of console.log()

Comment: Also care to explain why the line `UserDetailsDto userDetailsDto = new UserDetailsDto(userDatas, usersClients);` uses different constructor than the one specified in UserDetailsDto: `public UserDetailsDto(List<UsersClients> _usersClients)` ?

Comment: Thanks, with the developper tools I see that client = 1 but user = Object which contains a list of client. I thinks it is a Spring logic for ManyToMany relation ;) thanks.